# How to print a barcode using Crystal Reports in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How to print a barcode using [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)?

Comment: If you search online there are plenty of components for this - such as http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode_asp_net/

Answer (score 1):

If Crystal Reports doesn't have a barcode component, you could use a barcode font.